# Call a function from another function

Tags: jquery

I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ColorSwitcher is not defined
```

error.
what is my mistake? Also I want to make ColorSwitcher function to a callback function

```
var BackgroundColor = "red";
 jQuery(document).ready(function ColorSwitcher ($) {
            //add red color to some classes via variable
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("ul.colors .color2").click(function () {
        BackgroundColor = "pink"; // change the color
        ColorSwitcher(); //run the function again to change colors of the classes with new color
        return false;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `ColorSwitcher` function is in a different scope.  Try this:

```
var BackgroundColor = "red";
function ColorSwitcher ($) {
            //add red color to some classes via variable
}
jQuery(document).ready(ColorSwitcher);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("ul.colors .color2").click(function () {
        BackgroundColor = "pink"; // change the color
        ColorSwitcher(); //run the function again to change colors of the classes with new color
        return false;
    })
});
```

That way it's in the top-level scope where it can be seen by the second invocation.